# ": Command not found"

Tags: linux, shell, export, shebang

Some issue arise when sourcing one of your env file (a series of variable exporting)

for instance:

```
...
export MY_ROOT=/Soft/dev/blah/blah
export MY_BIN=${MY_ROOT}/bin
...
```

results in

```
$. my_env.sh
$echo $MY_BIN
/bint/dev/blah/blah
```

=> "/bin" seems to overwrite the begining of the variable instead of suffixing it..

Any idea?

By the way every time we source this file, an error message is reported:

```
": Command not found"
```

Which is weird.. This message appears even though we comment its whole content.

The invoked shell at the begining seems good `#!/bin/sh`, or `#!/bin/bash`.

What about control characters? How to screen them on linux?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash script always prints "Command Not Found"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362504/bash-script-always-prints-command-not-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fix the line endings in the file:

```
dos2unix my_env.sh
```

There's no need for a shebang in a file that's only going to be sourced since it is run in the current shell anyway. However, as a comment it might be informative for human readers.

Answer (score 3):

": Command not found" is the error I've seen when a UNIX/Linux shell script has been (mis-)handled by an MS Windows system.  For example if it was checked out using a WebCVS, modified using Notepad or WordPad, and then re-submitted.

(It's complaining that it can't find the [Ctrl-M] executable --- which is a perfectly valid, though extremely inconvenient and somewhat suspicious filename for UNIX/Linux).

Run the file through GNU `cat -A` or the `od -x` or `hexdump` commands to see these (and verify my diagnosis ... or run it through `tr -d` with the appropriate quoting and shell "verbatim" handling for your system.  (For example `tr -d '[Ctrl-V],[Ctrl-M]'` under Bash on a typical Linux system).

Depending on your version of `tr` you might be able to use: `tr -d '\r'` or `tr -d \015` (015 is the octal for CR, "carriage return" or ^M --- MS-DOS used to used CR/LF pairs as line termination, which is just one of the many reasons that MS-DOS can rot in the forsaken abyss when it comes to interoperability.  Line terminators of single characters cause no real issues for anyone else ... but PAIRS cause real conversion issues when everything else in the history of mainstream computing used single characters for this).

Oh, yeah, ***`vim`*** has a handy `set ff` (a.k.a. `set fileformat` option which can handle  UNIX, MacOS, and MS-DOS line termination conventions from any copy of `vim` regardless of which platform you're on.  I seem to recall the `vim` default is to detect which types of line termination a file is using and leave it unchanged (and to default to your platform's native for any new files, of course).

Comment: I've seen this too. It's almost always an incorrect linefeed issue. If the file is under version control try setting the linefeed setting (eg `svn:eol-style` if under SVN)

Comment: Right, both the odd looking variable value (really `$'/Soft/dev/blah/blah\r/bin'` with an embedded CR), and the error message are symptoms of having carriage-returns in the script file.