# Bash script prints "Command Not Found" on empty lines

Tags: linux, bash, debian

Every time I run a script using `bash scriptname.sh` from the command line in Debian, I get `Command Not found` and then the result of the script.

The script works but there is always a `Command Not Found` statement printed on screen for each empty line. Each blank line is resulting in a command not found.

I am running the script from the `/var` folder.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Hello World
```

I run it by typing the following:

```
bash testscript.sh
```

Why would this occur?

Comment: Seriously, net is full of such complaints. Shell is very weak and lame interpreter. Little here and there and it fails. You got to watch even all white spaces in script. My script was failing because of invisible line feed character. Probably this is only scripting language where white spaces count matters!

Comment: Use `bash -x scriptname.sh` to trace the error. – In my case it was a sh-file saved under Windows with VSCode and line endings as "CRLF". In VSCode in the bottom right corner you can change the line terminator from "CRLF" to "LF". Uploaded this file and could execute it finally with `bash scriptname.sh`.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings but many answers here explain a number of other situations where you get "command not found" for other reasons. Visitors are advised to **read all the answers** if your problem is not specifically about empty lines.

Comment: @Atul I can't agree with you more. That's why I write scripts in JavaScript, which makes it much easier to re-use modular code. Python works for this too.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Make sure your first line is:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Enter your path to bash if it is not `/bin/bash`

---

Try running:

```
dos2unix script.sh
```

That wil convert line endings, etc from Windows to unix format.  i.e. it strips \r (CR) from line endings to change them from `\r\n (CR+LF)` to `\n (LF)`.

[More details about the `dos2unix` command (man page)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix)

---

Another way to tell if your file is in dos/Win format:

```
cat scriptname.sh | sed 's/\r/<CR>/'
```

The output will look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh<CR>
<CR>
echo Hello World<CR>
<CR>
```

This will output the entire file text with `<CR>` displayed for each `\r` character in the file.

Comment: That's probably not necessary since he's running it directly with `bash scriptname.sh` (but it's still good practice, of course).

Comment: Hi #!/bin/bash is the first line of my script

Comment: That is true @paxdiablo.  david - can you post your entire script contents please?

Comment: Script updated.  I dont think its the script at fault - its probably the most basic a script can get

Comment: Can u also put the output of running 'env' commend?

Comment: Quotes dont make a different but removing the blank line gets rid of the problem.  It appears that for each blank line i have i get a command not found printed to the screen?

Comment: @chown - spot on - cheers.  It was edited in windows and its done something to the file.  If i create the same file through vi on the command line then i dont have the issue.  Is this something to beware of when working between windows and linux?

Comment: Yes, windows uses \r\n (CR+LF) where unix only uses \n (LF) for line endings.  Some things are ok with windows format on unix, but some times it does break files.

Comment: I thought it might be the CR+LF problem.

Comment: No, but consider that bash on linux uses `\n` as the end-of-line sequence, and if the line contains `\r\n` (due to windows text editor), then bash clearly wants to do something with the `\r` "word".

Comment: @chown - I had the same issue on Mac. I stumbled across this post. I am not sure if it helped the OP or not. But your solution helped me.

Comment: thanks. This was the exact the issue I was facing. This answers got it working.

Comment: How can you write an answer to a programming question while drive?

Comment: Sorry officer, I didn't mean to run the red light, I was saving the world (of windows users) on stack overflow

Comment: If you are running out of options in solving the above problem, give this answer a try. Totally saved me.

Answer (score 76):

You can use `bash -x scriptname.sh` to trace it.

Answer (score 63):

I also ran into a similar issue. The issue seems to be permissions. If you do an `ls -l`, you  may be able to identify that your file may NOT have the execute bit turned on. This will NOT allow the script to execute. :)

As @artooro added in comment:

> To fix that issue run `chmod +x testscript.sh`

Comment: To fix that issue run `chmod +x testscript.sh`

Comment: This was the answer that worked for me, Always got told I didn't have permission, so I sudo'ed it and was told command not found. I didn't think to check the permissions.

Comment: Thanks Lypso345, this solved the issue I was having.

Comment: chmod 777 testscript.sh FTW

Comment: This was the answer for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

This might be trivial and not related to the OP's question, but I often made this mistaken at the beginning when I was learning scripting

```
VAR_NAME = $(hostname)
echo "the hostname is ${VAR_NAME}"
```

This will produce 'command not found' response. The correct way is to eliminate the spaces

```
VAR_NAME=$(hostname)
```

Answer (score 18):

On Bash for Windows I've tried incorrectly to run

```
run_me.sh
```

without ./ at the beginning and got the same error.

For people with Windows background the correct form looks redundant:

```
./run_me.sh
```

Comment: Same on a linux-gnu bash system: 
`myscript` returns `bash: myscript: command not found`;
`./myscript` works

Answer (score 13):

If the script does its job (relatively) well, then it's running okay. Your problem is probably a single line in the file referencing a program that's either not on the path, not installed, misspelled, or something similar.

One way is to place a `set -x` at the top of your script or run it with `bash -x` instead of just `bash` - this will output the lines before executing them and you usually just need to look at the command output immediately before the error to see what's causing the problem

If, as you say, it's the blank lines causing the problems, you might want to check what's actaully *in* them. Run:

```
od -xcb testscript.sh
```

and make sure there's no "invisible" funny characters like the `CTRL-M` (carriage return) you may get by using a Windows-type editor.

Comment: +1 for the 'od' command!  That's cool, I didn't know about that!  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

use `dos2unix` on your script file.

Answer (score 7):

for executing that you must provide full path of that
for example

```
/home/Manuel/mywrittenscript
```

Comment: Indeed, the shell does not care about file extensions at all.  Not sure this merits being posted as a separate answer.

Comment: of course .in linux file system contrary to windows extensions are used merely as a part of the name and say nothing about file's content.I mustn't say **in my case** constraint.

Comment: thanks this helped me, I was giving just the filename and now it runs after I give it correct path

Answer (score 6):

Try `chmod u+x testscript.sh`

I know it from here:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/red-hat-31/running-shell-script-command-not-found-202062/

Answer (score 6):

If you have Notepad++ and you get this .sh Error Message: **"command not found"**
or this autoconf Error Message "line 615: 
../../autoconf/bin/autom4te: **No such file or directory"**.

On your Notepad++, Go to **Edit**  ->  **EOL Conversion** then check **Macinthos(CR)**.
This will edit your files. I also encourage to check all files with this command,
because soon such an error will occur.

Comment: Thanks for this. For my case I was running script on busybox linux distro. Had same error "not found" in all the empty lines in my scripts. it also had problems with if/else statement. changing EOL in Notepad++ to Unix fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem. Unfortunately

```
dos2unix winfile.sh
bash: dos2unix: command not found
```

so I did this to convert.

```
 awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print }' winfile.sh > unixfile.sh
```

and then

```
bash unixfile.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Problems with running scripts may also be connected to bad formatting of multi-line commands, for example if you have a whitespace character after line-breaking "\". E.g. this:

```
./run_me.sh \ 
--with-some parameter
```

(please note the extra space after "\") will cause problems, but when you remove that space, it will run perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you haven´t override the 'PATH' variable by mistake like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH="/home/user/Pictures/"; # do NOT do this
```

This was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having some of the `Cannot execute command`. Everything looked correct, but in fact I was having a non-breakable space `&nbsp;` right before my command which was ofcourse impossible to spot with the naked eye:

```
if [[ "true" ]]; then
  &nbsp;highlight --syntax js "var i = 0;"
fi
```

Which, in Vim, looked like:

```
if [[ "true" ]]; then
  highlight --syntax js "var i = 0;"
fi
```

Only after running the Bash script checker `shellcheck` did I find the problem.

Comment: `shellcheck` is available on-line, though you of course need to copy+paste your script exactly in order for that to help.  http://shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today, absentmindedly copying the dollar command prompt `$` (ahead of a command string) into the script.

Answer (score -2):

Add the current directory ( . ) to PATH to be able to execute a script, just by typing in its name, that resides in the current directory:

```
PATH=.:$PATH
```

Comment: This is considered a security vulnerability. **DO NOT ADD `.` TO YOUR PATH.**

Comment: Explanation on why this "answer" is a bad idea: https://superuser.com/questions/156582/why-is-not-in-the-path-by-default#156585

Answer (score -2):

You may want to update you .bashrc and .bash_profile files with aliases to recognize the command you are entering.

.bashrc and .bash_profile files are hidden files probably located on your C: drive where you save your program files.