# Bash commands not found — $PATH damaged

Tags: macos, bash, path, terminal

I accidentally made a mistake when I changed my `~/.bash_profile` file and now I'm unable to run any command, such as `ls`, `touch`, `sudo`, etc.

When I write `echo $PATH` I have this result:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:
$
```

And when I type `/bin/cat ~/.bash_profile`, I have this result:

```
export PATH=$HOME/local/node/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATHh
```

But I am unable to change it. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: how are you unable to change it?  can you use "`vi`" or "`emacs`" in Terminal?

Comment: You can also run `/usr/bin/open -e ~/.bash_profile` to edit `~/.bash_profile` in TextEdit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362504/bash-script-always-prints-command-not-found

Answer (score 26):

If you can do `/bin/cat`, you should be able to `/usr/bin/vi`, too.  Alternately, just fix it in your local shell:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

And then running your favourite editor should work again.