# Shell script saying Command not found. Ignoring shebang?

Tags: linux, shell

It seems like my shebang is being ignored. When I try to execute a shell script I wrote, I get an error:

```
% ls -alh /usr/sh
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  1011   139k Sep 16 01:29 sh
% ls -alh foo.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 george george    21B Sep 16 00:59 foo.sh
% cat ./foo.sh
#!/usr/sh
echo "lol"
% ./foo.sh
./foo.sh: Command not found.
% sh ./foo.sh
lol
```

**Yes, it's at /usr/sh**. I put it there.

But as you can see it works just fine when I instruct `sh` to execute it. What gives?

I don't think `$PATH` is applicable but in some search results trying to solve this problem, people have asked for it:

```
% echo $PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/root/bin
```

Comment: You need to give it execution permission to the current user.

Comment: You really have `sh` in `usr`?

Comment: chmod 755 foo.sh and your shebang is wrong, probably.

Comment: it is likely that there are windows line feeds in the file

Comment: Is the `sh` executable in your `/usr` directory?

Comment: Thank you all you super clever people. Yes, the `sh` executable is in `usr` on this machine, and the file was executable for the current user. The solution turned out to be that the line-feeds were in DOS format. I converted it to nix format with `nano` and voila!

Comment: Seriously, it's at `/usr/sh`? What kind of abomination is that? Also, you shouldn't be running as root, especially in a GUI, and when you are you should definitely have the `#` to show it.

Comment: The answer to this question I believe should be a summary of all the possible reasons you might get this issue. See my answer. I will gladly accept anyone else's answer over my own, if you can expand on it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash script always prints "Command Not Found"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362504/bash-script-always-prints-command-not-found)

Comment: I had recently to run in the same condition, and yes, like hek2mgl says, there are DOS/Windows line feeds "came somehow" to the file! Had to eliminate it all and correct functionality was restored!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this can be one of several things. To list the most common:

1. The file does not have executable permissions. Use `chmod a+x foo.sh` to give all users execute permissions.
2. Your shebang is incorrect, double-check the path. Use `which sh` and copy the result after a `#!`
3. Your lines are delimited with DOS feeds. Scripts need to be delimited with `\n`. Text editors such as `nano` allow you to convert by choosing `Write-out` then pressing `Alt+D` to toggle DOS format off. Utilities such as `dos2unix` can convert files directly on the command line (although it may need installing first).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your script file executable and try again.

```
chmod +x foo.sh
```

Comment: @deed02392 Is your selinux enabled? Can you try turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
% cat ./foo.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "lol"
% chmod +x ./foo.sh
% ls -l ./foo.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 deed  deed  0 16 sep 00:33 ./foo.sh
```

Note the path of **/bin/sh** and the executable bits.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do see your script is executable. It is the /usr/sh that bothers me... some UNIX/POSIX systems do not have it. Most of those that do are a link to a better shell.

Try `ls -l /usr/sh` to see what that shows.

You can also `printenv SHELL` and use the results as your script's shell. As this points to your login shell it is usually a good choice.