# How can I create .sh extension file in Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sh, daemons

I'm trying to write a script to run one of my `.jar` files as daemons, but I am not understanding how to create a `.sh` extension file in Ubuntu. I have already used `vi` to create a file with the code that I want, but I cannot figure out how to define the file to specifically be a .sh file. For example, I want to convert my file "`foo`" or "`foo.txt`" into "`foo.sh`".

Is there a simple command I am not seeing that can convert files to a .sh extension or is it a more complicated process?

Comment: `touch foo.sh`, `vi foo.sh`, `cat /dev/urandom > foo.sh`???

Comment: you should always do through research before asking here. There are so many tutorials explaining it http://linuxcommand.org/writing_shell_scripts.php

Comment: DevC, I used `CTR-f` on every page of those tutorials (both deprecated and current), and it does not mention ".sh" ever. I've also visited 3 other sites attempting to find an answer to this question and not a single one even mentions ".sh". Did that link previously lead to instructions that don't exist anymore?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use this as a template:

```
#!/bin/bash

# content of your script
```

The first line is called a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) and tells the OS what program that should be used executing the content of the file, in this case, `bash`.

To make the file executable:

```
chmod 755 foo.sh
```

To execute your script do:

```
./foo.sh
```

Comment: If you run into problems that the command or file is not found, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7362504/1066234 - And for my system, to execute the script I used `bash foo.sh`