# Linux shell script not found, but it does exist

Tags: linux, shell, openwrt

I created a shell script "/etc/aaa" on Openwrt which contains the following code:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    echo "Hello World!"
```

I also used this command to ensure the proper permissions:

```
chmod 777 /etc/aaa
```

Upon executing with any of the below 2 commands

```
sh /etc/aaa
```

or

```
ash /etc/aaa
```

it works well and prints "Hello World". The problem occurs when I try to execute it with this command:

```
/etc/aaa
```

where I get this error:

```
-ash: /etc/aaa: not found
```

Can anyone please explain why this is happening? What am I missing here?

Comment: Executable permission on the script is missing.

Comment: No, i've already used "chmod 777 /etc/aaa", i don't think it's related to permissions. Sorry i forgot to mention that

Comment: DOS newlines? Possibly only on the first (shebang) line?

Comment: Another thing that can screw this up is a UTF-8 "Byte-Order Mark" (which doesn't make sense, but I digress) What does `file /etc/aaa` think about your script, if you have `file`?

Comment: @EtanReisner Sorry i don't understand what you mean. What is DOS newline?

Comment: @ComputerDruid I don't have file command, but i tried to save /etc/aaa in both utf-8 encoding and windows-1252 encoding. But the problem stands still

Comment: What does `xxd /etc/aaa` or `hexdump -C /etc/aaa` or `od -x /etc/aaa` say (whichever you have that works)?

Comment: Re: "DOS newlines" -- if your file was created in Windows without an editor that understands UNIX text files, its lines will end with a two-byte CRLF sequence. UNIX only uses a single-character newline, so the extra character is treated as data on UNIX, and thus (for instance) part of the filename on the shebang. This means that instead of looking for `/bin/sh`, you get your OS trying to run `/bin/sh$'\r'`, which doesn't exist, hence the error.

Comment: What happens when you CREATE an executable file in /etc - So, for clarity, NOT FTP a file to it, but create it from scratch ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash script always prints "Command Not Found"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362504/bash-script-always-prints-command-not-found)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks for Charles Duffy's comment. It's really the CR LF problem.
Though i open the file in my linux virtual machine, since it has been modified in Windows. so enven in linux, the sublime text editor i use will think it's a windows file and use crlf as newline ending.

So ,just replace crlf with lf , the problem solved.

Answer (score 8):

Also worth checking that your shebang is correct, either: #!/bin/sh or #!/bin/bash