# Mac terminal -bash command not found?

Tags: macos, bash, path, terminal

I'm completely new to using terminal, and while trying to use `brew` to install some stuff, I did something to `PATH`. Now if I tell it to do something it always returns

> -bash: blah: command not found.

Is there any way to reset something to fix this? What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362504/bash-script-always-prints-command-not-found

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Your path is usually set in either your .profile or .bashrc file. These are found in the root of your user's home directory.

You should be able to fix them by running these two commands in the terminal. They contain the default executable paths

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

Comment: i'm new using mac, is script code in terminal or not ?

Comment: You would add these lines in whichever one of these files that exist.

/Users/YourUserName/.profile
/Users/YourUserName/. bashrc

Comment: this fixed my issue, but when I close terminal and reopened same error appears again

Comment: You should be able to just add these to the .rc file that your terminal uses to configure itself on startup. For bash terminal it would be .bashrc, for zsh terminal it would be .zshrc, etc. Some versions of macOs also use a .profile file. You would find or create the file in your user directory. ex. /Users/YourUserName/. bashrc

Comment: saved my life.thank u

Comment: I followed the manual step from the here https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally#manually-change-npms-default-directory as I did not have administrator access.

Comment: @JamesGrundner Why not in .bash_profile?  I saw many posts suggesting .bash_profile and I dont have neither .profile, nor .bashrc files in my /Users/UserName?  Thanks

Comment: still not working

Comment: getting -bash: ask: command not found

Comment: It helped a lot. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

You can set your `path` this way:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

and you can always add other directories if you want. Hope this helps.