# How to uninstall Python/pygame/Homebrew on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

When trying to install pygame for Python3 on my mac I mainly followed [this guide](http://brysonpayne.com/2015/01/10/setting-up-pygame-on-a-mac/). However, this ultimately didn't accomplish anything, aside from screwing something up in my Terminal path and giving me the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688932/mac-terminal-bash-command-not-found), which I can temporarily fix using the commands given in that thread, but I usually have to enter them again each time I close and re-open Terminal.

Next I tried just installing the 32-bit version of Python2 instead, and then doing the basic install of the corresponding version of pygame from pygame.org. This actually got pygame working to a certain extent, but it crashes immediately when I try to run a script a colleague wrote.

Which brings me here. I want to just uninstall everything and start from scratch so that I can hopefully find a way to correctly install pygame (it would be great if someone could point me to a guide for how to do this that isn't like 4 years old), and also to permanently fix the problem with my Terminal path. I grew up on Windows, so I already have a hard time uninstalling "normal" programs since OS X lacks a formal uninstall tool. So when it comes to uninstalling a program that was installed through Terminal and for which there is essentially no evidence of outside of some files in folders that are more or less hidden, I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 3):

follow the steps for ['Adding in a Permanent Location'](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/add-shell-path-osx/)

And with homebrew you can always run `brew uninstall <program-name>`

I'm sorry you are having so much trouble with unix, it really is an awesome operating system and once you learn the command line well I find it is much easier to get things done than on windows.