# NPM Packages Installing, but Not Showing Version Numbers on Command Line

Tags: node.js, npm

I have Node installed on my mac, running OS X El Capitan 10.11.6. When I NPM install packages, like express, nodemon, etc, and run, for instance "nodemon -v", I get a "bash: suchandsuch: command not found" return on my command line. When I run "node -v" or "npm -v" there's no problem. The correct, installed versions are returned. But even though I get successful installation messages on the command line when installing other packages through npm - like nodemon, express, etc, I always get the same error "bash: suchandsuch: command not found". Is this a path issue? A permissions issue? What do I need to edit?

Comment: Path issue it seems - check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29689064/6830901

Comment: Did you run `npm install` with the `-g` flag?

Comment: Yes, I ran it with the -g flag.

Comment: Tried running these two lines as described in the other thread, still no luck:


`export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"`