# Unexpected -bash command not found error when starting new mac terminal window

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I was messing around with ssh keys and permissions and other things I'm not too familiar with and ended up causing some problems on my mac, including denying myself permission to my user account, changing the root directory and other annoyances. Most of the other things were fixed by a restart or fiddling, but I know I get this error message every time I start up a terminal window and can't figure out what to do. How do I get rid of it?

I tried this [Mac terminal -bash command not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688932/mac-terminal-bash-command-not-found), but I don't think it's the same error because if I write `bash` into the terminal it starts a bash interface. Something is entering `-bash` into the terminal on startup and I can't figure out from where or why?

```
Last login: Tue Dec  4 08:57:20 on ttys003
-bash
Ludos-MBP-3:~ ludo$ -bash
-bash: -bash: command not found
Ludos-MBP-3:~ ludo$
```

Comment: You're better of asking at https://apple.stackexchange.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ since this is not a programming question. For starters I would check my .bash_profile file.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that something has been added to your shell profile. You can check by seeing if a file exists at `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.profile`). Variables and commands in this file are evaluated each time you open a new shell.