# .sh script does not run on SSH instance on Google Cloud

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

When I try to run a .sh script on an SSH instance on Google cloud, I get this error:

```
    bash: abc.sh command not found
```

This runs fine when I run it on the Google shell. I tried setting 'PermitUserEnvironment yes' in the sshd_config file but this did not change the output.

From my reading on similar issues, it seems as though I should be setting some other PATH variables but I'm not sure which ones these are.

Comment: Quick question: is the first line of your script `#!/bin/bash` ? If not, add it, run `chmod +x nameofyourscript.sh` and try to run it again

Comment: Yes, the first line is `#!/bin/bash` . And the file has permissions to be executed.

Comment: Are you trying to run it with the path as well? `/path/to/file.sh` Can you try as well with `source file.sh` and `bash file.sh`

Comment: What do you mean by "on an SSH instance" are you log in in the machine or you send the command trough SSH?

Comment: Thanks GalloCedrone, as you had guessed, it ran when I tried `./file.sh` while running the file from its directory.

Comment: I added an answer @AnishaJayadevan for future reference, adding why it was failing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was solved running the command with the path.

```
/path/to/file.sh
```

You were not able to run the command because bash was trying to locate that command inside the location specified by [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) enviroment variable since you were not specifying the path.

Future people reading could find as well useful information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362504/bash-script-always-prints-command-not-found) regarding possible causes.