# Use bash to find line in java files which include a pattern, and then replace another part of the line

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a directory that includes a lot of java files, and in each file I have a class variable:

`String system = "x";`

I want to be able to create a bash script which I execute in the same directory, which will go to only the java files in the directory, and replace **this** instance of *x*, with *y*. Here *x* and *y* are a word. Now this may not be the only instance of the word *x* in the java script, however it will definitely be the first.

I want to be able to execute my script in the command line similar to:

`changesystem.sh -x -y`

This way I can specify what the *x* should be, and the *y* I wish to replace it with. I found a way to find and print the line number at which the first instance of a pattern is found:

`awk '$0 ~ /String system/ {print NR}' file`

I then found how to replace a substring on a given line using:

`awk 'NR==line_number { sub("x", "y") }'`

However, I have not found a way to combine them. Maybe there is also an easier way? Or even, a better and more efficient way?

Any help/advice will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why do you want to pass `x` to the script? I think it would be easier to find the first occurrence of a line that starts with `String system =` and then replace the contents between `"`s.

Comment: This would also be useful. If you have a solution/code for this, could you post it as an answer? @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a `changesystem.sh` file with the following **GNU `awk`** script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.java; do
    awk -i inplace -v repl="$1" '
        !x && /^\s*String\s+system\s*=\s*".*";\s*$/{
            lwsp=gensub(/\S.*/, "", 1);
            print lwsp"String system = \""repl"\";";
            x=1;next;
        }1' "$f";
done;
```

Or, with any `awk`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.java; do
    awk -v repl="$1" '
        !x && /^[[:space:]]*String[[:space:]]+system[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*".*";[[:space:]]*$/{
            lwsp=$0; sub(/[^[:space:]].*/, "", lwsp);
            print lwsp"String system = \""repl"\";";
            x=1;next
        }1' "$f" > tmp && mv tmp "$f";
done;
```

Then, [make the file executable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-scripts):

```sh
chmod +x changesystem.sh
```

Then, run it like

```sh
./changesystem.sh 'new_value'
```

Notes:

- `for f in *.java; do ... done` iterates over all *.java files in the current directory
- `-i inplace` - GNU awk feature to perform replacement inline (not available in a non-GNU awk)
- `-v repl="$1"` passes the first argument of the script to the `awk` command
- `!x && /^\s*String\s+system\s*=\s*".*";\s*$/` - if `x` is false and the record starts with any amount of whitespace (`\s*` or `[[:space:]]*`), then `String`, any 1+ whitespaces, `system`, `=` enclosed with any zero or more whitesapces, and then a `"` char, then has any text and ends with `";` and any zero or more whitespaces, then
- `lwsp=gensub(/\S.*/, "", 1);` puts the leading whitespace in the `lwsp` variable (it removes all text starting with the first non-whitespace char from the line matched)
- `lwsp=$0; sub(/[^[:space:]].*/, "", lwsp);` - same as above, just in a different way since `gensub` is not supported in non-GNU `awk` and `sub` modifies the given input string (here, `lwsp`)
- `{print "String system = \""repl"\";";x=1;next}1` - prints the `String system = "` + the replacement string + `";`, assigns `1` to `x`, and moves to the next line, else, just prints the line as is.

Comment: Thank you for this in-depth answer! Would it be possible to have it without the printing of the line? It is sufficient just to have the line modified without printing

Comment: @luca That is what it does. Just modifies the first matched line.

Comment: I made the file out of your inplace code version and executed `changesystem.sh 'test'`, however I got the following error:

**changesystem.sh: Command not found.**

Do you know why I might be getting this error?

Comment: @luca See [How to make a file (e.g. a .sh script) executable, so it can be run from a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229589/how-to-make-a-file-e-g-a-sh-script-executable-so-it-can-be-run-from-a-termi) or [How do I run .sh scripts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-scripts).

Comment: I had already made it an executable by using chmod +x. The error still persists..

Comment: I added all details to the answer, and it works on my Ubuntu.

Comment: I appreciate that, however, I would like it to also work on my machine :) . I am using Red Hat, could that be the reason why there is the error on mine and not yours?

Comment: @luca Do you run it with `./` before the script file name? Please check the [Bash script prints "Command Not Found" on empty lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362504/bash-script-prints-command-not-found-on-empty-lines) thread.

Comment: A small error on my side when saving the file, but the **Command not found** error is now no more!

Comment: I did have another issue, but then I realised that the leading white-space in a line is quite important. In my java file, the line begins with an indentation of 4 spaces, and therefore the solution you suggested did not pick this up. I just added in the bash script 4 spaces before the word "String" and this did the trick. Just for completeness, would there be a way where it would pick up that there are leading white-spaces, do the change, and not alter the indentation structure of the java file?

Comment: @luca I added a GNU and non-GNU awk variations. Both support keeping the leading whitespace in a dynamic way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pre-compute the line number.  The whole job can be done by one not-too-complicated `sed` command.  You probably do want to script it, though.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $# -eq 3 ]] || {
  echo "usage: $0 <context regex> <target regex> <replacement text>" 1>&2
  exit 1
}

sed -si -e "/$1/ { s/\\<$2\\>/$3/; t1; p; d; :1; n; b1; }" ./*.java
```

That assumes that the files to modify are java source files in the current working directory, and I'm sure you understand the (loose) argument check and usage message.

As for the `sed` command itself,

- the `-s` option instructs `sed` to treat each argument as a separate stream, instead of operating as if by concatenating all the inputs into one long stream.
- the `-i` option instructs `sed` to modify the designated files in-place.
- the `sed` expression takes the default action for each line (printing it verbatim) unless the line matches the "context" pattern given by the first script argument.
- for lines that do match the context pattern,

  - `s/\\<$2\\>/$3/` - attempt to perform the wanted substitution

    - the `\<` and `\>` match word start and end boundaries, respectively, so that the specified pattern will not match a partial word (though it can match multiple complete words if the target pattern allows)
  - `t1` - if a substitution was made, then branch to label `1`, otherwise
  - `p; d` - print the current line and immediately start the next cycle
  - `:1; n; b1` - label `1` (reachable only by branching): print the current line and read the `n`ext one, then loop back to label `1`.  This prints the remainder of the file without any more tests or substitutions.

**Example usage**:

```
/path/to/replace_first.sh 'String system' x y
```

It is worth noting that that does expose the user to some details of `sed`s interpretation of regular expressions and replacement text, though that does not manifest for the example usage.

---

Note that that could be simplified by removing the context pattern bit if you are sure you want to modify the overall first appearance of the target in each file.  You could also hard-code the context, the target pattern, and/or the replacement text.  If you hard-code all three then the script would no longer need any argument handling or checking.